# How do I build an external link with Salesforce Essentials?

Tags: contact, custom-link

I have Salesforce Essentials (no API), so I'm not positive if this customization is even possible, but I wanted to try.

I have imported my customers with a custom field called "Legacy ID", which is the integer value of the record number in the ecommerce system where they live.  I'd like to build a link on the Contact Layout page to http://ecommerce-site.com/customer=LEGACY_ID.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do basic customization. In this case, you could use either a custom link or a custom field. As a custom link, simply go to Setup > Customize > Contacts > Buttons and Links (Classic) or Setup > Object Manager > Contact > Buttons and Links (Lightning), click "New" to create a new link, and enter in the URL, which would look like:

```
http://ecommerce-site.com/customer={!Contact.Legacy_ID__c}
```

Afterwards, go to the Page Layout screen, add this link to your page layout, and save the changes.

As a custom field, you'd go to the same Contact area from above, go to Fields (Classic) or Fields and Relationships (Lightning), create a new Formula field with a Text return type, and use a formula like:

```
HYPERLINK('http://ecommerce-site.com/customer'&Contact.Legacy_Id__c,
   'View on E-Commerce Site')
```

You can move this field around on the page layout as you like. It also has the advantage of being usable in reports.

Comment: I successfully created the custom link, then added it to my Contacts Page Layout as you suggested.  Worked great!  First timers adding a link to a page layout should follow the steps in [this Trailhead page](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_customization/units/lex_customization_buttons_links) under the heading "Create a Custom Detail Page Link."